# executing javascript: link + refreshing. JS + PHP

Tags: php, javascript, page-refresh

OK, so how can i make this link:

```
"javascript:elements.setPercentage('element1','".$value."')"
```

execute on my page, when the page is loaded?

Comment: You have 10 questions and you haven't accepted even a single answer! Wow! Please begin accepting answers.

Comment: @Crimson How do you mean accept answers? how to do that? :S

Comment: Click on the tickmark to the left of the answer you like most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can either put it in the body tag like this:

```
<body onload="function(){elements.setPercentage('element1','".$value."')}"
```

or in your javascript file:

```
window.onload = function(){elements.setPercentage('element1','".$value."')};
```

Or in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){elements.setPercentage('element1','".$value."')});
```

You need to wrap it in a function because you are sending arguments

Comment: Will it work even when the $value is a PHP string? I shall put <? echo ?> in, yea?

Comment: @Riki137 - Yes, you will need to handle the PHP as PHP. However, you should always use `<?php`, as short tags are not always supported in server environments.

Answer (score 1):

This example binds the `window.onload` event handler to an anonymous function. However, with this example, you can only have one handler (but as much code within it as you want).

jQuery, for example, has a more effective method called [onDOMReady](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) that you should consider.

```
<head>
... other stuff
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    if (typeof elements == 'object' and typeof elements.setPercentage == 'function') {
        elements.setPercentage('element1','<?php echo $value; ?>');
    }
}
</script>
... other stuff
</head>
```

Comment: @Riki137 - I'm not understanding you here. The PHP runs on the server, the JS on the client. If you have PHP variables in your JS, you have other problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using native JS:

`<body onload="/*whatever*/">...</body>`

If you're using JQuery (better cross browser support for the following):

`$(document).ready(function(){/*do whatever*/})`

Comment: Can i use onload on other tags? like <a>?

Comment: No, onload works only on 'body'. You should really use the JQuery alternative.